# AJAX sólo me toma datos de una sola consulta

Tags: javascript, ajax, php7

JavaScript:

```
    $(document).on("keyup", "input", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var buscar_categorias=$("#buscar_categorias").serialize();
        if (buscar_categorias!="") {
            alert(buscar_categorias);
            $.ajax({  
                type:"POST",
                url:"categorias.php",
                data:buscar_categorias,
                success:function(data) {
                    $(".filtro_categoria").html(data);
                }
            });
        }else{
            $.ajax({  
                type:"POST",
                url:"tabla_subir.php",
                success:function(data) {
                    $(".filtro_categoria").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
    $programas=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM programas");
    $cantidad_programas=$programas->num_rows;
    while ($p=mysqli_fetch_array($programas)) {
        echo "<details class='programa'>";
        echo "<summary>";
        echo $p['nombre_prog'];
        echo "</summary>";
        echo "<form id='buscar_categorias'>";
        echo "<input type='text' class='prog' name='id_prog' value='" . $p['id_prog'] ."' autocomplete='off'>";
        echo "<input type='text' class='categoria' name='categoria' autocomplete='off'>";
        echo "</form>";
        echo "<section class='filtro_categoria'>";
        echo "</section>";
        echo "</details>";
    }
```

Hay dos errores con este código: El primero es que la función AJAX sólo em toma el dato del primer programa (como pueden ver, cada programa se mostraría en `<details>`. Pondré ejemplos para ser más claro:

Así se verían los programas (cuando se clickean, se muestra una barra de búsqueda):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Empezando porque me debería mostrar una tabla y no me realiza el llamado (aunque esa no es mi prioridad).

El problema es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando ingreso una letra, siempre me coge el programa con id 1 y la categoría siempre será correspondiente a ese id. Además, de que me muestra todas las categorías en todos los programas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber cómo hago para limitar y evitar esos errores, por favor.

Comment: No puedes usar el mismo id para diferentes elementos.  El id debe de ser unico.

Comment: ¿Entonces reemplazo los id por class?

Comment: Asi es mi estimado.

Comment: Pues no sé como hiciste para entender la pregunta @alanfcm, yo la leí dos veces y no entendí realmente cuál es el problema. ¿? Por otra parte, veo muy raro que crees formularios dentro de un bucle. ¿Por qué no crear un sólo formulario Santiago y dentro de él los diferentes elementos, o bien un `select` o algo así?

Comment: Es un error que cometen mucho los principiantes, es por eso que me di cuenta del problema.

Comment: Ya cambié los id por class, me sirve en cierta parte, pero el input que contiene el id_prog no me lo toma ni lo envía.

Comment: Y aún así, el problema persiste. :(